# Timestamp operations in MongoDB when some timestamps are null

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection containing timestamp fields (TIMESTAMPVALUE) and I want to project it so that I only extract the hour from the timestamps. The problem is that some timestamps are null. The query is:

```
db.collections.aggregate([
  { 
    $project : {
      hour: {$hour: "$TIMESTAMPVALUE"},
      (...some other projections...)
    }
  }
])
```

When I run this, I get an error:

> { "serverUsed" : "localhost:27017" , "ok" : 0.0 , "errmsg" : "can't convert from BSON type null to Date" , "code" : 16006 , "codeName" : "Location16006"}

Is there an easy way to change this aggregation so that I get nulls in the `hour` field of the result, as one would reasonably expect, instead of failing the whole query, and preferably something simpler than splitting this into two pipelines, one handling nulls, the other handling non-nulls and then joining the results? I'm using MongoDB 3.4.

Comment: try with https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/ mongo functions.

Comment: I was thinking about it, but I'm not sure if that will help - `$ifNull` doesn't serve as a ternary operator, I would need something akin to `timestamp==null ? null : hour(timestamp)` but MongoDB's `$ifNull` can only substitute null values with a different value, so I would only be able to transform null timestamps to non-null timestamps, but that's not what I need. `$ifNotNull`  would actually help, but it seems there's no such thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it. The solution is :

```
db.collection.aggregate([                                                                                                                                                                                          
  {
    $project : {
      hour: { $cond:
        [ { $eq: [ "$TIMESTAMPVALUE", null ] }, null, { $hour: "$TIMESTAMPVALUE" } ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```